# Making directory like layout with RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-view

This is what I want to achieve

[image]

What I have tried is, dynamically adding layouts to recycleView on click of each item. But I don't think this is an efficient way.

Mind you it's a directory like structure, where each folder can have sub folders and each subfolder can have subfolders and so on.

Please suggest any other alternatives.

Comment: which things did you find for that? all i can think of by now to implement it by yourself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why do you want to reinvent a wheel? There's a library called [RecyclerTreeView](https://github.com/TellH/RecyclerTreeView) with exactly that functionality. At least you can view sources and perform necessary changes on your own.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for! Have a good day